# Non-plastic straws in Germany?

Tags: plastic, plastic-alternatives

I want to find non-plastic straws. Are there are any in Germany, that you can physically buy?

I live in Bavaria. I have a big Edeka, Rewe, Lidl and Rossmann nearby, but I am ready to travel "great" distances in the search of non-plastic straws.

I found Superhalm ([Eatapple](https://www.kaufda.de/insights/wo-gibt-es-superhalm-eatapple-aus-die-hoehle-der-loewen-zu-kaufen/)), which seems to be available only online (I am not comfortable with e-purchases for a series of unrelated to this post reasons).

Comment: If the big supermarkets near-by don't sell paper or metal straws you can try and ask them if they can order it for you. If enough people do this it will be added to their product range. BTW it should only be a matter of time before it becomes available. [Single-use plastics like straws will be banned in the EU in 2021](https://ec.europa.eu/environment/efe/content/european-parliament-votes-single-use-plastics-ban_en) Meanwhile you could also try to [grow your own straws](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/3110/99)

Comment: @THelper I will tell them. Moreover, I will try to not use at all until the get available, I think... Maybe you should post an answer, since the answer seems to be no.

Comment: @Erik I found some glass-made straws in Karstadt, with a spear-morphed sponge. WMF had a cup-like thing, with an attached straw - doesn't fit my needs. Leonardo is not around... Depot on the other hand seems to have a plethora of straws, from variations of what I found in the others, to Bamboo and paper straws - although I am not sure what's better - in Hellas I used from Cane (straw in Hellenic is "Canie" (Cane = Καλάμι, Straw = Καλαμάκι).  I think you answered perfectly my question in your comment, so, please, post an answer, with **Depot** as the winner! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Karstadt/Kaufhof, or any store specialised in kitchen stuff, maybe WMF, maybe Leonardo, even Depot could provide at least bamboo straws. I got some glass straws (via the Internet, boooh) by Halm, very happy with them.

Generally speaking, I wouldn't go looking for good knifes or pots at a supermarket, so I also wouldn't bother looking there for sustainable straws - at least not today. Maybe in ten years ;-)

Comment: Let's hope that non-plastic straws and such will become the de facto "soon", thanks for the answer!

Comment: @gsamaras: I also saw some reusable straws at DM the other day.

Comment: Aha, will have it in mind, thanks!